# Trigger Jenkins Job from Azure DevOps

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, cicd

I want to trigger Jenkins Job when anyone pushes the code in Azure DevOps Repository. However, when I set up Jenkins Service Connection in Azure DevOps I am getting the following error:

> Failed to query service connection API: 'JenkinsURL'. Error Message:
>   'A task was canceled.'

I have tried enabling port 8080 in the VM to resolve this.

Comment: Microsoft has extensive documentation on setting this up.  Are you running into specific issues?  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/

Comment: Yes, when I set up Jenkins Service Connection in Azure DevOps I am getting below error.   Failed to query service connection API: 'JenkinsURL'. Error Message: 'A task was canceled.'

Comment: Have you tried any steps to resolve this yet?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled 8080 port in VM.

Answer (score 2):

The error message you have provided indicates that this is a problem with the configuration that could be permission related.  Here are some steps to help resolve this issue:

- You can [follow guides](https://medium.com/@bbenz/azure-devops-and-jenkins-in-perfect-harmony-8c92ff980723) where other people have configured the two.  Pay special attention to the permission settings that are selected.
- Double check your permissions on the servers.  While you may have configured Jenkins to communicate with Azure DevOps, you still need to make configuration changes in DevOps.
- Double/Triple check your URLs on both systems.  I've been burned by dropping an **s** on http or missing a character on a copy paste.
- If you are setting this up within Azure check the [Azure Role Based Access Control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) to make sure proper permissions exist.

Comment: For testing, I didn't try to Verify the connection and save the Service connection. Then I have added the "Queue Jenkins Job" task in Build Pipeline and I got below error.  ##[error]crumb request failed.
HttpResponse.statusCode=500
HttpResponse.statusMessage=Server Error
Crumb request failed.
HttpResponse.statusCode=500
HttpResponse.statusMessage=Server Error
##[error]crumb request failed.

Comment: That's an internal error then.  Are you passing parameters in?  If so can you provide them?

Comment: I have resolved this. During  Service Connection setup I have passed Token instead of a password. But when I click on Verify connection still its giving me same error. I have clicked on the Ok button and setup Build Pipeline including "queue Jenkins Job" task and pipeline is working while Verify connection is failing.

Comment: For More Information, I am getting below error in Azure DevOps Service Hook for Jenkins.  
 **An error occurred while sending the request.
    Unable to connect to the remote server
    A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond xxx.x.xx.xx: xxx**